# UIScrollView created in Interface Builder scrolls out of the view

Tags: uiscrollview, interface-builder, ipad

I'm trying to create a scrollable area in the middle of the screen - above it are a few non-scrolling labels, and below it are some non-scrolling buttons, so I only placed the `UIScrollView` in interface Builder in the middle of the window. I set the outline of the `UIScrollView` to be the full width of the iPad, 768 pixels, and about 700 pixels high.

I can place other UI elements within the `UIScrollView` as children of it, and I can scroll those by setting (in the view controller):

```m
#define SCROLL_AREA_VERTICAL_HEIGHT 1200
...
[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, SCROLL_AREA_VERTICAL_HEIGHT)];
[myScrollView setNeedsDisplay];
```

When I look at this in Interface builder, it seems to work, I can see only the UI elements that happen to fit with in the 700-pixel or so frame of the `UIScrollView` as set in Interface Builder. When I actually run it, though, I can see the UI elements that should be hidden below the lower boundary of the UIScrollView frame, and when I scroll up, the elements at the top don't become hidden by the top edge, but rather move up and over the labels on the top that are supposed to be static. In other words the boundary of the scroll area isn't actually hiding the elements that scroll off of it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well i had a problem that was a bit like yours, don't know if it would work for you but try selecting the view in interface builder, and in the atributes inspector there is a box with a checkmark that sais clip subviews, check it and try. That was the solution for me. Hope it helps.